# Is there a way, in Rails, to get the correct url for a form when the model doesn't match the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, crud

I have a model called User, and a controller called ManagersController. Some users are managers as marked by a field (role = "manager"). I have a more or less standard REST CRUD but the _form template ended up looking like this:

```
= form_for(@user, :url => @user.new_record? ? managers_url : manager_url(@user))
```

I have some very similar cases in other forms and I'm sure I'm not the first one to encounter this. Is there a way to generate the proper URL out of @user without having the ternary operator in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method that does the logic you're describing is [`polymorphic_url`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7280787a53436046e992305a235e66e4fb458e0f/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb#L90) and it cannot do what you suggest.

You might want to make your own helper method for this, or create a subclass that is actually called "Manager".

```
class Manager < User
  default_scope where(:role => "manager")
end
```

Which one you choose depends on details of your application which I cannot help you with.